# Password Regex Gov Reqs

Tags: php, mysql, regex

For government prime contractor, looking to apply a password regex per their requirements:

1. At least one uppercase
2. At least one lowercase
3. At least one number
4. At least one special character

Have the following code:

```
if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))) {
    $passwordErr = "Please enter a password.";
    } elseif(trim($_POST["password"]) === $username) {
        $passwordErr = "Cannot be the same as your username";
    } elseif(trim_check($_POST["password"]) == TRUE) {
        $passwordErr = "Please do not use a space in your password.";
    } elseif(!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\x21-\x7E])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9A-Za-z\x21-\x7E]{6,50}$/',($_POST['password']))) {
        $passwordErr = "Must be six to fifty characters in length and at least one of each: <ul><li><strong>Uppercase</strong></li><li><strong>Lowercase</strong></li><li><strong>Number</strong></li><li><strong>Special Character</strong></li></ul>";
    } else {
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    }
```

The function its being passed to only trims the whitespace before making sure there is no whitespace:

```
function trim_check($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = preg_match('/\s/',($data));
    return $data;
}
```

There are two things I want to ask about:

1. Is `\x21-\x7E`appropriately defined using php regex for ascii in both parts of the expression (see #2 for what I mean by both parts).
2. What is this portion of the expression `[0-9A-Za-z\x21-\x7E]` doing that this portion `(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\x21-\x7E])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])` is not already doing?

It appears to work fine, but I don't know if I'm missing something. The best I can tell it's saying that it must contain at least:
 1 Uppercase
- 1 Lowercase
- 1 Number
- 1 Special Character (any except for a space), and
- It must be a letter, number and special character (but I feel this is redundant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your current regex, broken across multiple lines for readability:

```
^
    (?=.*\d)                     \
    (?=.*[\x21-\x7E])             \
    (?=.*[a-z])                   /  assert some conditions
    (?=.*[A-Z])                  /
    [0-9A-Za-z\x21-\x7E]{6,50}   --  match here
$
```

The first four positive lookaheads *assert* that a number, special character, lowercase, and uppercase letter occur one or more times in the pattern.  But the thing is, lookaheads assert but do not actually *match* or consume anything.  So, the final portion of your regex does this:

```
[0-9A-Za-z\x21-\x7E]{6,50}
```

Note that the above also restricts to characters only from the above mentioned types, and it only allows between 6 and 50 characters.

Comment: Gotcha, assert and match. Thanks. And it appears the syntax is correct, and I believe I've included all the necessary ascii characters. Appreciate your time!